# Getting next available number, skipping items in an array

Tags: javascript

I have got an array that contains non available slots. for instance [4,6,7]
If I start counting up (index++) once it get's to 3, the next available slot would be 5.
If index = 5, the next available slot is 8.

I can't find a decent way to do that. How can I develop a function, that returns the next available slot (given a counting direction up, or down)

```
var notAvailable = [4,6,7];
function nextSlot(current, direction) { ... }

nextSlot(2,'up');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does `current` variable refer to the current index or to the current value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this...

```
var notAvailable = [4,6,7];

function nextSlot(current, direction) { 
   var inc = 1;
   if( direction == "down" ){
       inc = -1;
   }
   var next = current + inc;
   for(var i = 0; i < notAvailable.length; i++){

      if( notAvailable[i] == next ){

         return nextSlot(next , direction );

      }

   }

   return next ;

}

nextSlot(2,'up');
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `current` as the current slot:

```
var notAvailable = [4,6,7];

function nextSlot(current, direction) {
  var inc = direction === 'down' ? -1 : 1;
  var next = current;

  while(notAvailable.indexOf(next += inc) > -1);

  return next;
}

nextSlot(2, 'up'); // 3
nextSlot(3, 'up'); // 5
nextSlot(5, 'up'); // 8
nextSlot(5, 'down'); // 3
nextSlot(3); // 5 assumes no direction as 'up'
```

It uses [array's indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method of ES5.